# How do I perform custom Configuration File transformations in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: .net, configuration, app-config, transform, .net-4.5

I'm building an .NET 4.5 Application which I eventually run through ILMerge to produce a single `.exe` and a single `.exe.config` at the end.

I have a post build event which does 2 things.

1. Run ILMerge and place the combined assembly in $(ProjectDir)\Lib\
2. Xcopy bin\orignial.exe.config => $(ProjectDir)\lib\combined.exe.config

The last step I need to perform is a cleanup of the contents of the config file. Any type+assembly references in the original config need to be replaced stating that type is now located in the new assembly. For example, the app also uses and merges in `Unity` so in the original.exe.config that section entry is

```
<section name="unity" 
     type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.UnityConfigurationSection,
           ***Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration***" />
```

Whereas in the merged assembly, it needs to change to

```
<section name="unity" 
     type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.UnityConfigurationSection,
           ***Combined***" />
```

I know there's a built in Config File Transformation tool for altering the config file based on the build (Debug/Release) you are performing. Just wondering can this be leveraged for custom purposes or am I going to be stuck hand-crafting some find & replace code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to use CTT; A command line XDT Transformation tool.

http://ctt.codeplex.com/

http://outcoldman.com/en/blog/show/223

Seems like it'll do what I need in conjunction with ILMerge.